# How to extract coordinates from a specific contour?

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates, contour

I need to find contour-specific coordinates, as can be seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiIhN.png). I am able to draw a specific contour (highlighted in red) but the `.txt` file is giving the same set of coordinates, even if I am changing the contour.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("ceramic.bmp")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,55,255,0)
_th,contours, hierarchy = 
cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print" Number of contours detected %d.>"%len(contours)
cv2.drawContours(im,contours,55,(1,70,255)) #-1 fills it
area = cv2.contourArea(contours[55])
print (area)
cv2.imshow("Contours",im)
text_file = open("contour_list_55.txt", "w")    ##### Write the 
coordinates (x,y) of a contour in an txt file python 
text_file.write( "%s"% contours) 
text_file.close()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: Can we label each contour with numbers and then it will be easy to find any particular contour with the above code. Kindly help with this

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are writing all the contours to file, not just a single contour.

You are drawing a contour with index 55:

```
area = cv2.contourArea(contours[55])
```

But your command for the .txt file is:

```
text_file.write( "%s"% contours)
```

It should be something like:

```
text_file.write( "%s" % contours[55] )
```

That is if you want to get coordinates of the same contour that you draw.

I also generally suggest you to follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle in programming. If you have a constant (like 55) you should define it and use it by name throughout your code. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

THRESHOLD = 55
CONTOUR = 55

im = cv2.imread("ceramic.bmp")
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,THRESHOLD,255,0)
_th,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print "Number of contours detected = %d" % len(contours)
cv2.drawContours(im,contours,CONTOUR,(1,70,255))
area = cv2.contourArea(contours[CONTOUR])
print (area)
cv2.imshow("Contours",im)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
coords = np.array2string(contours[CONTOUR])
open("contour_%d.txt" % CONTOUR, "w").write(coords)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

It will write the coordinates to file `contour_55.txt`. And if you want to change to another contour, you just have to change the constant CONTOUR.

Comment: Can we label each contour with numbers and then it will be easy to find any particular contour with the above code. Kindly help with this